# How to capture http POST requests with browsermob-proxy and selenium

Tags: post, selenium, proxy

Hello trying to capture the actual POST data in an HTTP POST request using browsermob proxy + selenium test framework. So basically i'm running an automated test using selenium and I want to capture the key/value pairs and the actual POST data of a HTTP POST request during the test. Using the following logic I can only capture the key/value pairs of the POST header but not the actual POST data (aka the form field id values). Is there a way to actually capture the POSTDATA (like sniffing applications do such as tamper/live headers in firefox)?

```
ProxyServer proxyServer = null;
proxyServer = new ProxyServer(9101);
proxyServer.start();

proxyServer.setCaptureContent(true);
proxyServer.setCaptureHeaders(true);

Proxy proxy = proxyServer.seleniumProxy();
proxy.setHttpProxy("localhost:9101");

//selenium test config code, omitted for brevity

proxyServer.addRequestInterceptor(new HttpRequestInterceptor() {
public void process(HttpRequest request, HttpContext context) throws  HttpException,  IOException {
   Header[] headers = request.getAllHeaders();
   System.out.println("\nRequest Headers\n\n");
       for(Header h : headers) {
           System.out.println("Key: " + h.getName() + " | Value: " + h.getValue());
       }

   }
});
```

An alternate way I read about but could not get to work was to configure the following flags in the browsermob proxy server to true:

```
proxyServer.setCaptureContent(true);
proxyServer.setCaptureHeaders(true);
```

Then output the actual HAR file:

```
Har har = proxyServer.getHar();
Date date = new Date();
har.writeTo(new File("c:\\tmp\\har_" + date.getTime()));
```

To see the key/value pairs, POST Data, and actual content of the response... but when I parse the HAR file... I only see the key/value pairs of the POST header again... no POST data... no response content. I am only interested in the actual POST data though.

Comment: Never mind figured this out eventually after checking out the browsermob proxy project to my workspace. The 
proxyServer.setCaptureContent(true) and 
proxyServer.setCaptureHeaders(true) should work to capture POST params inside the HAR obj only. The proxyServer.addRequestInterceptor WILL NOT capture the POST params.

Comment: This comment should really be an answer. But thank-you for the comment!

Answer (score 0):

I also had same problem. As a solution, I captured all the data, converted the HAR file into JSON, and then filtered out only POST requests from the JSON file.